# Find the algebraic equation of the ellipsoid of known orientation inscribed in a cuboid of known dimensions

Tags: geometry, 3d, solid-geometry, quadrics

Given a cuboid of dimensions $2 a \times 2 b \times 2 c$, and given a $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix $R$, I want to inscribe an ellipsoid whose axes are respectively along the directions specified by the columns of $R$.  Find the lengths of the semi-axes along the three directions.

**My thoughts:**

The cuboid can be centered at the origin, and its faces made parallel to the coordinate planes.  The equation of the ellipsoid then is

$ r^T Q r = 1 $

where $ r =[x,y,z]^T $ and $Q$ is a $3 \times 3$ symmetric positive definite matrix.

Tangency to the faces of the cuboid results in $3$ independent linear equations in the diagonal matrix of the reciprocal of the squared semi-axes lengths, which can be solved, and check for positiveness of all components of the solution vector.

Comment: The equation of an ellipsoid never has the term $xyz$

Comment: Indeed error, I had in fact in mind only the second degree $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/c)^2-xy/(ab)-yz/(bc)-zx/(ca)= 1$ when principal axes are not parallel to coordinate axes.

Comment: Yes.  Something like that.